# syntax error typeorm when trying to run the migration

Tags: typescript, typeorm

When i ran npx typeorm migration:run i got an error like this :

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.

I've asked many people and i don't know how to solve it.
here is my *ormconfig* and my *package.json* respectively:

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "docker",
  "password": "docker",
  "database": "db_project_manager",
  "entities": [
    "./src/models/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "migrations": [
    "./src/database/migrations/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "./src/database/migrations"
  }
}




{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --inspect --transpile-only --ignore-watch node_modules src/server.ts",
    "typeorm": "ts-node-dev ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "pg": "^8.6.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "typeorm": "0.2.24"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.6",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.21.2",`enter code here`
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4"enter code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think typeorm migrations support Typescript files out of the box. You might need to change your `package.json` like below:

```json
"entities": [
  "<PATH_TO_YOUR_DIST>/models/**/*{.js,.ts}"
],
"migrations": [
  "<PATH_TO_YOUR_DIST>/database/migrations/**/*{.js,.ts}"
],
```

You can find `<PATH_TO_YOUR_DIST>` inside `tsconfig.json` file -> `compilerOptions` -> `outDir`.

Sometimes you might have a `src` directory inside your `<PATH_TO_YOUR_DIST>`. In that case, you will have to append that in the path (`<PATH_TO_YOUR_DIST>/src`) as well.